# If date less or more than 15 minuites (If Sunset or Sunrise)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, conditional-statements

I am trying to work with date to getting now is **sunset** or **sunrise**.

*Since im not sure how to do with **If Else statement** about **Date***

I got data when is sunset and when is sunrise.

But was wondering how to do condition if current date is sunset or sunrise with `+-15 minutes`

**Example :**

Current date : 2015-12-17T**17:45**:00 *(or between 17:45 to 18:15)*

Sunset : 2015-12-17T**18:00**:00

Rusult = **Sunset** (because `+-15 minutes`)

**Here is my code so far :**

```
var SunData = {'set':'2015-12-17T09:14:56', 'rise':'2015-12-17T15:10:52'};

var date = new Date();
    date = date.getTime();

var sun_rise = new Date(SunData['rise']);
    sun_rise = sun_rise.getTime();

var sun_set = new Date(SunData['set']);
    sun_set = sun_set.getTime();

var sunRiseSetDiff = 900000; // 15 minutes

// Here
var result;
if(false) {
    result = 'sun-rise';
} else if (false) {
    result = 'sun-set';
} else {
    result = 'none';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gd1s1o0y/

Can you help me about **If Else statement** ? Thanks

Comment: `new Date(SunData['rise'])` uses *Date.parse* to convert a string to a Date, which is notoriously unreliable. You should use a simple function to parse the string to a date. There is no need for all the *getTIme* calls, just use the dates directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean

```
var result = 'none';
if(Math.abs(date - sun_rise) <= sunRiseSetDiff) {
    result = 'sun-rise';
}
else if(Math.abs(date - sun_set) <= sunRiseSetDiff) {
    result = 'sun-set';
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/87eqtejq/)

Comment: thanks so much, i saw your comment on @gurvinder373, what is different ?

Comment: Nothing. Mine was first and use less code :) and I initialise to none instead of adding another if

Answer (score 2):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1r62a8u7/1/)

```
var SunData = {'set':'2015-12-17T09:14:56', 'rise':'2015-12-17T15:10:52'};

var date = new Date();
        date = date.getTime();

var sun_rise = new Date(SunData['rise']);
        sun_rise = sun_rise.getTime();

var sun_set = new Date(SunData['set']);
        sun_set = sun_set.getTime();

var sunRiseSetDiff = 900000; // 15 minutes

// Here
var sunsetResult = Math.abs( date - sun_set ) > sunRiseSetDiff ? false: true;
var sunriseResult = Math.abs( date - sun_rise ) > sunRiseSetDiff ? false: true;

if(sunriseResult) {
    result = 'sun-rise';
} else if (sunsetResult) {
    result = 'sun-rise';
} else {
    result = 'none';
}

alert(result);
```

Comment: @mplungjan yeah, just that I made changes into his code and you did it from scratch :)

Comment: @mplungjan which initialization is not used?

Comment: He had `var result;` you go one worse and now have a global var. I rewrote his because I dislike unused initialisations. Not a comment on your code which I just now notice is not using var at all

Answer (score 1):

Just a re-write of your function with comments.

```js
// Always parse date strings manually, you can use a library if you want
// but a bespoke function is pretty simple if the format is guaranteed
// and is a valid date
function qParse(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2], b[3]||0, b[4]||0, b[5]||0, b[6]||0);
}
    
// The OP seemed to have sunrise and sunset transposed
var sunData = {'rise':'2015-12-17T09:14:56', 'set':'2015-12-17T15:10:52'};

// There is no need for getTime, date objects can be used in simple
// arithmetic directly
var now = new Date();
var buffer = 9e5; // 15 mintues

// Initialise result to a default string
var result = 'Not near sunrise or sunset';
    
// Change value if near sunset
if (Math.abs(now - qParse(sunData.set)) <= buffer) {
  result = "Close to sunset"; 

// Otherwise, change value if near sunrise
} else if (Math.abs(now - qParse(sunData.rise)) <= buffer) {
  result = "Close to sunrise"; 
}
    
// Show result
document.write(result);
```